# Elasticsearch. How to calculate score with freq term?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to set up Elasticsearch, is there any way to correct the calculation of the field _Score? For example, a user writes a request for "daiw", and I have the word daiwa, which has a freq = 3651, then how can I first show the results of the daiwa at the request of daiw?

I'm just trying to figure out how the search works.

Answer (score 0):

`elasticsearch` use BM25 algorithm for scoring to view details you can look at this article https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables
for the use case searching for `daiw` and `daiwa` re not the samething when you re using the standard `analyzer` you can use search by `fuzziness` in order to retrieve data for `daiwa` using `daiw`